# MS Word Master document - display all subdocuments on opening

Tags: microsoft-word

I wonder if there is any possible way to make a master document open with all subdocuments expanded, and Master document shown in normal mode. I would prefer that the readers do not need to open the document, go to the view-tab, press outline, press expand documents and then press close outline view every time they should read anything in the document.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do at least part of this with a simple macro. You can record the macro, or use this VBA code:

```
Sub OpenAllSubDocs()
'In a master document, opens all the sub documents.

If ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Count >= 1 Then
 ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded = True
End If

End Sub
```

In theory, you should be able to make this happen when the document opens, using Private Sub Document_Open, but I haven't gotten that to work, so I won't include it in the answer.